# How can you return all of the numbers that you loop through in an array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a year picker from the years 1901 to the year 2021, to do this I've created a loop and an empty array in where I store all the values from the loop. The loop goes from 1901 to 2021. The problem is that I don't know how to render those values one by one. I've tried doing a map on the array and return those values, but it returns all the array and not the values one by one.

Here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './signup.css'

function Signup() {
  const [useEmail, setUseEmail] = useState(true)
  const [year, setYear] = useState([])

  const toggleEmail = () => {
    if(useEmail) {
      setUseEmail(false)
    } else {
      setUseEmail(true)
    }
  }

for (var i = 1901; i < 2021; i++) {
    year.push(i)
}

console.log(year)
    return (
        <div className="modalsignup">
          <div className="modal____popupform">
          <img  src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/twitter-logo-png/twitter-logo-vector-png-clipart-1.png" className="twitterLogo____signup" />
          <h1 className="signup_____headertext">Create your account</h1>
          <input placeholder="Name" className="placeholder____divcreateaccount"/>
          {useEmail ? <input placeholder="Email" className="placeholder____divcreateaccount" />: <input placeholder="Phone" className="placeholder____divcreateaccount"/>}
          <div>
            <button className="switcher_____button" onClick={toggleEmail}>Use {useEmail ? "phone" : "email"} instead</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h4 className="birthdate____signup">Date of birth</h4>
            <p className="birthdate______paragraph">This will not be shown publicly. Confirm your own age, even if this account is for a business, a pet, or something else.</p>
          </div>
          <div className="selector_____options">
            <div>
              <select className="selector_____months">
                    <option value="0">Month</option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <select className="selector_______days">
                        <option value="0">Day</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <select>
                        <option>{year.map(get => {
                               return get
                        })}</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button className="signup_____button">Next</button>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Signup
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

And here is the outcome I'm getting with the map method:

Any help I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by viet is correct, but he might have missed few things , you need to pass value and key for option after mapping

Other observation do not loop inside a function like that , the reason is every time the React remounts the for loop will run and no need of using useState unless you are changing state , so use a loop outside the React Function it will run only once

```
const getYears=(start,end)=>{
  let _years=[]
  for(let i=start;i<=end;i++){
    _years.push(i)
  }
  return _years
}

let years = getYears(1901,2021)

export default function App() {
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
              <div>
                <select >
                    <option value="0">Month</option>
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">May</option>
                    <option value="6">June</option>
                    <option value="7">July</option>
                    <option value="8">August</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">October</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <select className="selector_______days">
                        <option value="0">Day</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <select>
                      {years.map(get => {
                               return  <option value={get} key={get}>{get}</option>
                        })}
                       
                      </select>
                    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can refer to codesandbox below if you need
[image: Edit hungry-shirley-zw5vh]

Answer (score 0):

Just move `option` inside `map`:

```
<select>
  {year.map((get, i) => {
    return <option key={i}>{get}</option>;
  })}
</select>
```